# org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker. When and why is this used?

Tags: java, spring

I am new to `Spring` world.

I would like to know when and why to use `org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker`?

In my project I see this in `applicationService.xml` and it is taking a TOPIC (sonic) as target object and targetMethod as subscribe.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was more explicit in older version. In [3.1.x javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/) for `MethodInvoker` said: *Typically not used directly but via its subclasses MethodInvokingFactoryBean and MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean*

And you find usage example in `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` javadoc:

*An example (in an XML based bean factory definition) of a bean definition which uses this class to call a static factory method:*

```
 <bean id="myObject" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
   <property name="staticMethod" value="com.whatever.MyClassFactory.getInstance"/>
 </bean>
```

*An example of calling a static method then an instance method to get at a Java system property. Somewhat verbose, but it works.*

```
 <bean id="sysProps" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
   <property name="targetClass" value="java.lang.System"/>
   <property name="targetMethod" value="getProperties"/>
 </bean>

 <bean id="javaVersion" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
   <property name="targetObject" value="sysProps"/>
   <property name="targetMethod" value="getProperty"/>
   <property name="arguments" value="java.version"/>
 </bean>
```

TL/DR: `MethodInvoker` is seldom used by itself, but its subclasses like `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean` are (were) used to execute arbitrary methods in XML configuration files.

Comment: Serge Ballesta - I think the short answer for my question is subscribe method is invoked to read the TOPIC (sonic) but I will go thru the java doc  again to figure out how the methods are invoked. Thanks for your time